# 0x Price/Quote API doesn't handle different token decimals correctly

Tags: 0x

I am using the 0x Price and Quote API for my project and encountered the following Problem which could be a bug in the API.

Example request: https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=0x514cdb9cd8a2fb2bdcf7a3b8ddd098caf466e548&buyToken=0x95ad61b0a150d79219dcf64e1e6cc01f0b64c4ce&sellAmount=91852168466729

Token Decimals:

- 0x514cdb9cd8a2fb2bdcf7a3b8ddd098caf466e548 has 9 Decimals
- 0x95ad61b0a150d79219dcf64e1e6cc01f0b64c4ce has 18 Decimals

The response includes the following values among others:

- "buyAmount": "17621716298148718"
- "sellAmount": "91852168466729"
- "sellTokenToEthRate": "681573019064660.96173915"
- "buyTokenToEthRate": "131484453.43337870913186545"

sellAmount is corrently based on 9 Decimals
--> sellAmount / sellTokenToEthRate = 0.13476497146 ETH
which is correct.

However buyAmount is also based on 9 Decimals
--> buyAmount / buyTokenToEthRate = 134141724.605
which is not correct and 9 decimals off the correct value.

Is this a know issue or am I doing something wrong here? Appreciate the help!

Comment: Early in your question you say one token has 9 decimals and the other 18, then later you say buyAmount and sellAmount are both 9 decimals. That wouldn't make sense. They will have the number of decimals that their their respective asset has

Comment: This is why I asked the question. I guess that it's a bug in the API. Shouldn't the results of `sellAmount / sellTokenToEthRate` and `buyAmount / buyTokenToEthRate` be about the same?

Answer (score 0):

As temporary workaround I'm using a multiplier for calculating the eth value of the buyAmount:

```
const sellTokenToBuyTokenDecimalMultiplier: BigDecimal = 
  new BigDecimal(`1e${sellTokenDecimals}`,)
    .divide(new BigDecimal(`1e${buyTokenDecimals}`), 19);

const buyValueInEth: BigDecimal = 
      new BigDecimal(buyAmount.toString())
        .divide(buyTokenToEthRate, 18)
        .multiply(sellTokenToBuyTokenDecimalMultiplier);
```

(Hint: BigDecimal is https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-big-decimal)